# Strange gap occurring in simple HTML + CSS page

Tags: html, css, margins

I'm building a very simple web page that will be segmented into 4 even quarters of the page, with a div in each corner. I'm running into this weird problem though - One of the divs keeps acting like something is above it, but I can't see anything there when I inspect the element. Here's an image:
[image]

Here is the complete HTML and CSS (It's not very long):

```
<html>

<head>

    <style type="text/css">

        *{
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Helvetica", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        }

        html, body{
            height: 100%;
        }

        h2{
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            margin-left: 5%;
        }

        .qrtr{
            width: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 50%;
            background: darkgrey;
        }

        #cat{
            width: 90%;
            height: 80%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-left: 5%;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #viewer{
            width: 90%;
            height: 80%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-left: 5%;
            background: white;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="qrtr">
    <h2>Catalog</h2>
    <select id="cat" name="cat" size="50">
        <option>Hello</option>
        <option>Palm Trees</option>
        <option>Chocolate Milk</option>
        <option>Code</option>
    </select>
</div><div class="qrtr"><h2>View</h2><div id="viewer">

    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

When I inspect the elements, I can see no reason for that gap to be there. I've tried messing around with some of the CSS to get it into position but I can't figure out the right way to do it. More than I want to find a solution to this, I'd really like to understand why it's behaving that way when I clearly haven't written any CSS to make it do this intentionally. Anyone know what's causing this? It even does it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3fjcuoL/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is given in the last sentence of http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

The `select` element in your first `div` defines its last line box.  The `h2` element in your second `div` defines its last line box.  (The `viewer` doesn't have a line box, because it has no content.)

Therefore, the `div`s are aligned so that the `select` and the `h2` are "sitting" on the same line.

Knowing this, there are a couple solutions to the problem:

1. Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.qrtr`'s style:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.qrtr {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50%;
  background: darkgrey;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#cat {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#viewer {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="qrtr">
  <h2>Catalog</h2>
  <select id="cat" name="cat" size="50">
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Palm Trees</option>
    <option>Chocolate Milk</option>
    <option>Code</option>
  </select>
</div><div class="qrtr">
  <h2>View</h2>
  <div id="viewer">

  </div>
</div>
```

2. Add `overflow: hidden;` (or `overflow: auto;`) do `.qrtr`'s style:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.qrtr {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50%;
  background: darkgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#cat {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#viewer {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="qrtr">
  <h2>Catalog</h2>
  <select id="cat" name="cat" size="50">
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Palm Trees</option>
    <option>Chocolate Milk</option>
    <option>Code</option>
  </select>
</div><div class="qrtr">
  <h2>View</h2>
  <div id="viewer">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works to fix the problem, but I'd like to know why it needs that overflow property. How does this work? I'd just like to understand this so I don't run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```css
        *{
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Helvetica", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        }

        html, body{
            height: 100%;
        }

        h2{
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            margin-left: 5%;
        }

        .qrtr{
            width: 50%;
            float:left;
            height: 50%;
            background: darkgrey;
        }

        #cat{
            width: 90%;
            height: 80%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-left: 5%;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #viewer{
            width: 90%;
            height: 80%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-left: 5%;
            background: white;
        }
```

```html
<div class="qrtr">
    <h2>Catalog</h2>
    <select id="cat" name="cat" size="50">
        <option>Hello</option>
        <option>Palm Trees</option>
        <option>Chocolate Milk</option>
        <option>Code</option>
    </select>
</div><div class="qrtr"><h2>View</h2><div id="viewer">

    </div>
</div>
```

Change the CSS for qrts to

```
    .qrtr{
        width: 50%;
        float:left;
        height: 50%;
        background: darkgrey;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I would use this solution but unfortunately I avoid using floats. :( You are right though. This solution would work.

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing with this and not just feed him markup.